# Variable scope for TCL global

Tags: tcl, global

If I set a local variable to refer to a global variable in a proc, can sub-proc's also access the variable?

```
proc function1 {} {
    global CAR

    function2
}

proc function2 {} {
    echo ${CAR}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  Each proc must redeclare the variable as `global`.

Answer (score 1):

you can either access a variable with his full qualified name `$::CAR` or you can access a variable in one of the callers (caller of caller etc) with `uplevel`. Otherwise you need a `global`.